# How to know if BigQuery data stream operation is finished

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

```
    function insertHandler(insertErrors, apiResponse) {
```

If I receive apiResponse and no insertErrors, does this mean that the import is finished or that the import is started (currently importing)?

I am trying to do a query on the imported data and I have to know when the import is successfully finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you stream data - it first goes into so called "streaming buffer"
Underneath - streaming buffer is actually bigtable. As soon as your data in streaming buffer  - you can safely query it along with data that is already in the bigquery table, because underneath - bigquery engine queries not only bq table but also respective bigtable as a federated source.

Which means that jobs.insert and jobs.query APIs (and their respective client's specific implementations) will work perfectly for you.

At the same time please note, tabledata.list API (and respective clients methods) will not return data that is in streaming buffer